# Почему получается успешно возвращать значения из функции по ссылке и по адресу?

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, ссылки

Я знаю, что нельзя возвращать ссылки и адреса локальных переменных, потому что эта ссылка или адрес будет указывать на адрес уже уничтожившейся переменной, т.е. - на мусор. 
**Вопрос:** Но почему в таком случае удается возвращать значения таким образом и всё работает как надо?
Пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int& doubleValue(int a) {
    int value = a * 2;
    return value;
}
int *doubleVal(int a) {
    int value = a * 2;
    return &value;
}
int main() {
    cout << doubleValue(2) << endl;
    int val1 = doubleValue(3);
    cout << val1 << endl;
    int &r1 = doubleValue(5);
    cout << r1 << endl;

    cout << *doubleVal(4) << endl;
    int *val2 = doubleVal(3);
    cout << *val2 << endl;
    int &r2 = *doubleVal(7);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Программа верно выводит все значения. Почему?

**UPD:**
В моей книге был пример с возвратом локального указателя из функции:

```
struct free_throws {
     int made;
     int attempts;
     double percent;
};
const free_throws & clone(free_throws &ft) {
     free_throws *pt;
     pt = &ft;
     return *pt;
}
```

**Вопрос:** можно ли в этом случае вернуть локальную переменную-указатель. если да, то почему?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1120056/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82-rvalue-ref-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8/1120122#1120122

Comment: По дополнению - я думаю, лучше задать вопрос по этому примеру кода отдельно.

Comment: @insolor задал только что

Answer (score 1):

Неопределенное поведение - оно такое неопределенное....

Понимаете, вы можете перебегать дорогу на красный свет светофора. Можете переходить ее с завязанными глазами и заткнутыми ушами. И у вас это будет отлично получаться... до поры до времени.

И то, что после нескольких переходов вы остались живы и здоровы - является ли основанием говорить, что "на красный переходить можно, я проверял!"?

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Но есть еще один вопрос:  в книге С. Прата был код с возвратом локальной переменной-указателя. Я сомневаюсь правильно так делать или нет, и является ли это тем случаем, когда я перехожу на красный светофор? (Я дополнил вопрос)